# USB ports not working on Xubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: usb, xubuntu

Basically, my USB ports on my IBM Thinkpad T43 have stopped working most of the time. Sometimes, they mount and appear in Nautilus, but other times, they aren't recognized.

The timeline of events on this laptop for the past few months:

1. Started having problems after using a USB port hub. The port would sometimes work but would be fixed with the occasional reboot.
2. Re-partitioned/Expanded my Xubuntu partition (I have a Windows XP/Xubuntu dual boot).
3. Now the majority of the time, the USB fails to recognize devices. In addition, the few times they are recognized, the device may suddenly disconnect.

Things I've noticed:

- The devices still receive power from my computer (I can charge my ipod..etc..)
- I can't understand `dmesg` outputs.
- I don't know if `lsusb` is telling me anything useful.

My `dmesg` output is here: http://pastebin.com/KdNxHcFC

Things start to get weird at the bottom of the file.

And my `lsusb` is:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: Does the answer at http://askubuntu.com/questions/117524/usb-device-not-accepting-address help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jesus.
That was an intense 15 minutes.

So I went the question as linked by alex_mayorga and I found a simple grub line fix. Then, I updated grub, rebooted, and was greeted by a older looking grub. I thought whatever, this must be a side-effect and selected my distro. Logged in, opened chrome, and plugged in devices. First one mounted, but second one didn't. :I

And then later, I got a black screen of death. (I didn't know it was possible)

Rebooted, and my arrows keys wouldn't work and this older grub wouldn't automatically select an OS after some odd seconds. So I forced a shutdown and tried again. No success.

Panic now. Rebooted again, greeted by newer-looking grub, logged in. Phew. Plugged in my devices again, both mount! Great! Must have been a freak computer breakout. Not! I get the black screen of death again.

Reboot, and go straight for the grub file, revert it back to post-incident and so far, it's been fine. Both devices mount.

I don't know what happened but this sequence of events has thoroughly tired me. I'm gonna do my work now.

Answer (score 0):

Hope I'm not wasting your time but I had weird problems with my usb ports.
Had to go into bios setup and disable usb 3.0 support.

Comment: I wish I had USB 3.0... but I don't. I only have one USB 2.0 and USB 1.1 .