# My USB Keyboard isn't working

Tags: 14.04, usb, keyboard, mouse, dmesg

I have just installed Ubuntu and now my USB keyboard and mouse are not working.

I plugged in a PS/2 keyboard so i can now execute commands.

I get a lot of strange messages in `dmesg`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9269795

The USB keyboard and mouse were working fine while installing from the Live CD.

The USB keyboard works in BIOS.

Comment: Possible wiring fault? Do they still work fine when connected to another machine?

Comment: @ElderGeek: yes, they work absolutely fine when connected to another machine. They also work fine in BIOS. I have one of those BIOS with a mouse so I can test both there.

Comment: @Rinzwind: How do I fix it?

Comment: ha found something on arch: "Enable IOMMU in bios, and optionally(?) add iommu=soft or iommu=pt to boot command kernel line."  https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=186503

Comment: There's a very old thread here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=797789&page=2
answer by trippedn looks promising.

Comment: @ElderGeek 71 is a protocol error. Might be something different.

Comment: How about ... http://askubuntu.com/questions/117524/usb-device-not-accepting-address  Same error and has an accepted answer ;)

Comment: @ElderGeek: Also, I have to note, that I disabled Legacy USB in BIOS, someone told me to check Plug and Play is enabled in BIOS, but I couldn't find it. Additionally, I followed the steps here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=797789

Comment: @Rinzwind: I tried the solution out, but still not working.

Comment: @ElderGeek: I also disabled the splash and I can see that it does "see" the internal hub, but I cant make out if it sees the keyboard.

Comment: @MDTech.us_MAN boot up, with the device connected - run `lsusb` and see if the system can see the keyboard device.

Comment: @ThomasW. see here for the output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9271551/

Comment: lsusb does not show my usb keyboard and mouse either and both work, so that may not be definitive. Have you tried using a different usb port? It's possible something in linux may be conflicting on that port.

Comment: @James: I tried all ports available. I will try to find some drivers maybe on the manufacturer website. Though it does work on the Live CD. Maybe there is a way to copy the driver from there...

Comment: @Rinzwind: Thanks! Your post pointed me in generally the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed this problem by enabling IOMMU in BIOS. This seems to be a motherboard specific issue.

Forum thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2111223&p=12503485#post12503485

> Just wanted to add to this thread in case in helps someone -- I have
>   also been experiencing this bug (Networking and USB not working with
>   64-bit Linux kernels on the Gigabyte 970A-D3 Rev. 3.0 motherboard). I
>   originally posted about it in [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12499970) if you want gory details.
>
> Note that my motherboard is a D3, not a DS3, though they are almost
>   identical.
>
> Also note my motherboard is Rev. 3.0. The Revision is important as it
>   has a different bios than the earlier Revs; also, I did not have this
>   problem with the earlier Rev that I used briefly.
>
> Further note, 32-bit kernels work fine, it's only the 64-bit ones that
>   don't have successfull Networking and USB.
>
> And further note - the same problem exists in the current 13.04 Raging
>   64-bit kernel as well.
>
> The good news: I was able to get my system working by setting IOMMU to
>   ENABLED in the bios (it was set to disabled by 'optimized
>   settings'/defaults).
>
> YMMV. I figured out that I should play with this setting by going
>   through this thread and the similar launchpad bug mentioned earlier (
>   ), though I don't know if anyone else solved it by the same method.
>
> Not 100% sure where this bug should be reported to. Its not strictly a
>   Ubuntu bug, it affects all 64-bit kernels (that I tried, at least). I
>   guess it might be considered primarily a gigabyte bug. Not sure. I do
>   feel, though, that it would be better if the kernel gave some more
>   useful warning / debug messages in this case so people could diagnose
>   it better. I ended up spending many hours working on this.

Comment: Excellent! Glad I could point you to the correct solution :)